# Need to delete and then insert a record at same mapping

Tags: informatica

Here is my picture but it's wrong  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHDPZ.jpg  i need to delete and insert at the same time in [enter link description here](https://www.informatica.com//#fbid=BNdnUfLTonu)

Comment: Your Image is not working, And please be elaborate the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question in a better way.

But, with what you wrote, I guess you want a mapping that can insert some records and delete some records based on a condition. Is that right?

I've seen the image and I would design the mapping by the following way:

You can link `ECH_Source` only on the `ECH_Router` and then link the `ECH_Router` on your target, that is, all the fields from `ECH_Sourcer` should pass by the `ECH_Router` before they get to the target.

Then you must duplicate your target and link `ECH_Router` on both of them. One target will be used to delete records and the other one will be used to insert records.

And then all you need to do is write the right condition on your router's output groups and configure your targets. One for deleting records and the other one for inserting records.